# How to deal with this"E/System﹕ Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer"

Tags: android

```
05-27 08:21:21.538  31650-31659/com.yiliantech.wifi E/System﹕ Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
05-27 08:21:21.538  31650-31659/com.yiliantech.wifi E/System﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.finalize(WifiManager.java:2134)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I got this problem,and I can't find what caused it.Colud anybody help me,thanks

Comment: Could you publish the code causing the error?

Comment: But...It's too long,I don't know which part should I publish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would most likely occur if a thread didn't catch an exception.

From the stack trace, I'd assume you're making a thread?
Inside the run method, wrap everything inside a `try` block. Then log all `Exception`'s.

Example

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
myThread.start();

class MyRunnable extends Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            // Your code, where the exception was thrown
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Here we are logging the exception to see why it happened.
            Log.e("my app", ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It tells him what type of exception it was-  a null pointer exception.

Comment: Somewhere it must tell you what line of code caused the null exception, so you can investigate the source of the problem.

Comment: The question is tagged with `Android` tag, so you should not recommend the usage of Thread. Thread is a crime in Android!

Comment: @shimatai I assumed the OP was creating a Thread. The idea was to wrap the entire block of code in a try-catch so they can narrow down the problem.